# AWS Glue - finding schema reference for table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Using AWS CDK 2 for creating schemas and tables, I seem to have problems linking the `schemaReference`

```js
const schema = new glue.CfnSchema(this, "User", {
  compatibility: "NONE",
  dataFormat: "JSON",
  name: "user",
  schemaDefinition: JSON.stringify(userSchema),
});

new glue.CfnTable(
  this,
  "UserTable",
  {
    catalogId: this.account,
    databaseName: "my_db",
    tableInput: {
      name: "users",
      tableType: "EXTERNAL_TABLE",
      storageDescriptor: {
        location: "my_db.public.users",
        schemaReference: schema,
      },
      parameters: {
        classification: "postgresql",
        typeOfData: "table",
        connectionName: "rds_conn",
      },
    },
  }
);
```

It seems like I'd expect `schemaReference` to be able to use the Cfn output in some way? I can only get this working by hard coding a `schemaReference` object with a `schemaVersionId` that I find in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to lock the schema version in its definition, then to reference the schema by name. Example

```js
new glue.CfnSchema(this, "User", {
  name: "user",
  // ...
  checkpointVersion: {
    versionNumber: 1,
  },
});

new glue.CfnTable(
  this,
  "UserTable",
  {
    // ...
    tableInput: {
      // ...
      storageDescriptor: {
        // ...
        schemaReference: {
          schemaId: {
            registryName: "default-registry",
            schemaName: "user",
          },
          schemaVersionNumber: 1,
        },
      },
    },
  }
);
```

Though verbose, it has the advantage of being portable across stacks.